# react-datesのDateRangePickerでminDate,minDateが効かない

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

minDate,minDateが効きません
また、DateRangePickerを読み込むとwarningが発生するのですがこちらも解消できません。
DateRangePickerの開発が止まっているようなのですが、現在のバージョンと合わなくなってしまっているのでしょうか？

```
'use client'
import moment from 'moment'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates'
import 'react-dates/initialize'
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css'

export const Hoge: React.FC= () => {

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null)
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null)
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState<
    'startDate' | 'endDate' | null
  >(null)


  console.log(moment('2024-03-10').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  console.log(moment('2024-03-01').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      startDate={startDate}
      startDateId="startDateId"
      endDate={endDate}
      endDateId="endDateId"
      focusedInput={focusedInput}
      onFocusChange={setFocusedInput}
      maxDate={moment('2024-03-10')}
      minDate={moment('2024-03-01')}
      onDatesChange={(selectedDates) => {
        setStartDate(selectedDates.startDate)
        setEndDate(selectedDates.endDate)
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "yarn clean:dist && yarn clean:next && next build",
    "clean:dist": "rimraf src/**/dist",
    "clean:next": "rimraf .next out",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development next build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}'",
    "schema": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts",
    "local:stg": "yarn clean:dist && yarn build:development && yarn next build && yarn start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.9.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typed-document-node": "^5.0.6",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.2.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.167",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.15.11",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.102.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/react-dates": "^21.8.6",
    "@vanilla-extract/css": "^1.14.1",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "gsap": "^3.7.1",
    "header-case": "^3.0.0",
    "i18next": "^23.10.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.2.0",
    "i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mui-daterange-picker": "^1.0.5",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "next-i18next": "^15.2.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-datepicker": "^6.2.0",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.5",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.20",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.58",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vanilla-extract/next-plugin": "^2.3.6",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": "yarn format"
  }
}
```

[image: エラー]